# if --fast is used to sync geth in ethereum node, can it be used for mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

using --fast does not download the full blockchain only the blockheaders ,then 
if --fast is used to sync geth in ethereum node, can it be used for mining??
will it mine same as a node synced normally?